# Best ways to transport few items within Germany?

Tags: germany, relocation

I'm an expat living in Munich, Germany. I'm planning to move to a different city within Germany (Karlsruhe) soon and I will need to find a moving service for that. However, my current and also my next apartment are furnished, and aside from 3-4 packages (each weighing ~5-10 kilos) and a home working desk, I don't have anything else that I would need to bring.

I don't have people that could help me with the relocation, nor I have a driving license to rent a van or car. What other options do I have to transport these items within Germany?

Comment: I think this probably _is_ in scope for Expatriates.  Most natives would either have a driving license, or would know somebody they could ask that did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of options:

- A standard removals firm - you won't need a pantechnicon, but you'll need a van for the desk.
- A man+van type operation (ask locally).
- Standard parcel service (the desk will be expensive)
- Websites that allow you to advertise your work to (often small) delivery firms.  I used to use AnyVan in the UK.